# how to make a PEM (proton exchange membrane) out of Nafion Dispersions?

Tags: electrons, polymers, fuel, chemical-engineering, protons

I would like to use a Nafion membrane for a fuel cell project, but the Nafion sheets are hard to integrate. Therefore, I would like a gel type of Nafion that can take the shape of the container I put it in e.g. 5 cm^3 Cube). When researching, I found out about Nafion™ Polymer Dispersions which are a liquid form (thick).

Is there a guide on how to use it to fabricate a proton exchange membrane? Do I require other materials (chemicals) to mix with the Dispersions to make the PEM?

My ideas:

1- Dry the Nafion solution under 120C until all H2O is evaporated hoping for the dry polymer to be adhesive.

2- Mix the Nafion solution with either PVA or agar to give it a gel-like structure. I don't know if that will affect protons' pathways.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you put your thought in the text so that we can suggest whether it'd work or not and other proposals, which would work.